# Unable to change animation image using the animation function in Java

Tags: java, animation, nullpointerexception

I would like to address this as a non-duplicate because I could not find any answers on google. There are similar questions but the answers are not what I wished for.

Below is what I believe is important for the animations

**here is whats inside my player class:**

```
...
...
Animation ani;
Animation ani2;

public Player(double x, double y, Texture tex, StarDestroyerAlpha game, Controller c) { 
    super (x,y); 
    this.tex = tex;
    this.game = game;
    this.c = c;

    ani = new Animation(3, game.getSpriteSheet(), game.getSpriteSheet1(), game.getSpriteSheet2(), game.getSpriteSheet3(), game.getSpriteSheet4(), game.getSpriteSheet5());
    ani2 = new Animation(3, game.getSpriteSheet21(), game.getSpriteSheet22(), game.getSpriteSheet23(), game.getSpriteSheet24(), game.getSpriteSheet25(), game.getSpriteSheet26());

}

}

public void tick() { //movement of player
    x += velX;
    y += velY;

    if (x<=0) 
        x = 0; 
    if (x>= 1280 - 70) //there will be space because of the sprite size
        x = 1280 - 70;
    if (y<=0) 
        y = 0;
    if (y>= 800 - 85) {
        y = 800 - 85;
    }

    ani.runAnimation();
}
```

here in my mouse event class:

```
    ...
    ...
    Player p;
    ...

public MouseInput(StarDestroyerAlpha game, ShipSelection ship, Texture tex, Player p) {
    this.game = game;
    this.ship = ship;
    this.tex = tex;
    this.p = p;

}
    ...
    ...
    ...
    if(my >300 && my < 500 && shipRotation == 1) {
        game.setDestroyerLogo(game.getDestroyerLogo2());
        game.setPilotImage(game.getPilotImage2());
        game.Health = 300;

        p.ani = null;
        p.ani2.runAnimation();


        }

    }
```

So my logic is that the player is able to select 2 skins, which have their own unique animations.

I set up 2 animations and the first one(ani) is the default. Once the player selects the second skin, the animation images will change. However, it gave me an error after I select my 2nd skin. (the game is able to keep going but the with the skin being default)

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at star.destroyer.alpha.MouseInput.mouseClicked(MouseInput.java:107)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

My possible guess on the cause of this issue is that you can not switch images in an animation?

If anyone knows the answer on the fix please answer down below. Thank you!

If you are unsure what I am asking, feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: *"There are similar questions but the answers are not what I wished for."* Tough. But more widely, why aren't the answers what you wished for? Why should we attempt to answer this if there's a (good) chance we'll come up with the same answers you don't like? General tips: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: Welcome to SO. **"I believe is important for the animations"**  you'll know for sure when you have created [mcve].  Then post it.